# Animation map in R error in Loading shapefile in R

Tags: r, maps, animation, animatedmarker

I want to make an animation map in R. 
I have tried several command lines but I get some errors, as follows:

```
> library(raster)
> s <- shapefile("//Users//Merry//Desktop//ro_judete_poligon//ro_judete_poligon")
Error in .local(x, ...) : file.exists(extension(x, ".shp")) is not TRUE
```

or this command

```
library(rgdal)
> ro_judete_poligon<-readOGR(dsn="C://Users//Merry//Desktop",layer="ro_judete_poligon.shp")
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open data source
```

How can I get the shapefile in R? 
I am confused.

Comment: In Windows, you use *single* forward slashes or double *back*slashes - so these two should be paths to your desktop: `C:\\Users\\Merry\\Desktop` or `C:/Users/Merry/Desktop`

Answer (score 1):

`readOGR` syntax can be a bit unfriendly at times. Here's a suggestion.

Assuming your shapefile path is - `C:/Users/Merry/Desktop/ro_judete_polgion.shp`, the following should work:

```
library(rgdal)

#try without specifying a layer
ro_judete_poligon <- readOGR("C:/Users/Merry/Desktop/ro_judete_poligon.shp")
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. And I receive this error:

Error in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source

Comment: I tried again and it works. The right formulation was without [.shp].  Finally, it works! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: `readOGR` either has *one* argument which is the path to the shapefile *with* `.shp`, or *two* arguments, the first (dsn) is the path of the folder containing the shapefile, and the second (layer) is the shapefile name *without* `.shp`.